# Cordova plugin success callback loses bind variable

Tags: javascript, cordova, callback, bind, cordova-plugins

I am passing a success callback to a Cordova plugin, as below,

```
function onSuccess (response) {
    console.log('i = ' + this.i + ', response = ' + response);
}.bind ({i: i})
```

The value of i is not retained. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging, learned that the Cordova layer run-time session does not carry forward 'this'.
So, when the callback is eventually run within a session of the Cordova layer, the 'this' is not what the bind value is, but the value then.

In short, what I was trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Nothing is impossible my friend